# Can't get overridden OnPaint function to work for custom Panel - C#

Tags: c#, overriding, panel, onpaint

I'm trying to create a border for my Panels that can change in thickness and color. After doing some research, I discovered that the only good way to do this is to create my own custom Panel and to override the OnPaint function. This is what I've got:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    public CustomPanel() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        {
            int thickness = 30;
            int halfThickness = thickness / 2;
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, thickness))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(halfThickness,
                     halfThickness,
                     ClientSize.Width - thickness, ClientSize.Height - thickness));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomPanel cp = new CustomPanel()
    {
        BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        Margin = new Padding(0),
        Size = new Size(45, 45)
    };

    cp.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);
}
```

Note: I'm not entirely sure what the part about SetStyle in the constructor is, but some people said that helped them. No luck for me.

Anyways, the last line of code gives me an error that says, "No overload for 'OnPaint' matches delegate 'PaintEventHandler'."

And before you say, "change OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) to OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)," if I do that I get the error message, "'CustomPanel.OnPaint(object, PaintEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override."

So I'm not really sure what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why you want to attach handler to `Paint` event? Just remove the line `cp.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);` and you are done.

Comment: and of course make sure you add `cp` to `Controls` collection.

Comment: Huh, ok. I just assumed you added it like you would for other events like a mouse click.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Thanks!